# How can i avoid the duplicate Field counter from two user at the same time pressing the bottom

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

i have collection which contains the whole users products , and to avoid the casts of reading all docs to get the length of the collection ,  i increase one value  +1 to every field once it's doc being created  , ok now everything is ok

here i am using this method to chick if doc if exist or not so i can avoid the duplicate of counter in case offline mode

```
 removeProduct1(){
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("product").doc('product1')
        .get(const GetOptions(source: Source.server)).then((value1) {
      if(value1.exists) {
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("product").doc('product1').delete();
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("product").doc('productCount').update({
          'productCount': FieldValue.increment(-1),
        });
      }
    }).onError((error, stackTrace) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar,);
      });
  }
```

also everything is ok , but i noticed if two user pressed the button for this method at the same time so its gonna be two value decrease -2
maybe someone will think its rarely when two user hit the button at the same time , well this is only simple sample of what i have for real instead , i have page which contains too many users which is not be rarely for being two user hit the button

**EDIT FOR MOER EXPLATION**

i have collection called `Friends` which contains User IDs of friends together
for example user1  his id is `ABC` and user2 his id is `DEF`
so id becomes final into the `Friends collection` like this `ABCDEF` by following `function`
and also this following `function` increase counter +1 for ever one of them

```
makeFriends(){
  // here i make sure first if the friends Ids are not exists To avoid suspiciously increasing the counter in offline mode and its work very well 
  

    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Friends").doc(user1Id+user2Id).get().then((value) {
        if(!value.exists){
          // here to add ids to the friends collection 
          FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Friends").doc(user1Id+user2Id).set({
            'test':''
          });
          //here to increase counter in other colection which is users for both user 
          //user1
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user1Id).update({
        'friendsCounter':FieldValue.increment(1)
      });
      //user2
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user2Id).update({
        'friendsCounter':FieldValue.increment(1)
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Okay now everything going fine and they became a friends with one value increased and their Ids became unit into Friends collection .. and here image for better explanation

[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJewE.png)

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSrIK.png)

here i have `function` responsible for deleting friend with decrease one value from `FriendsCount Field` for both of them

```
deleteFriends(){
  // here i make sure first if the friends Ids are exists To 
  // avoid suspiciously decrease the counter in offline mode and its work very well
  FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Friends").doc(user1Id+user2Id).get().then((value) {
    if(value.exists){
      // here to remove ids from the friends collection
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Friends").doc(user1Id+user2Id).delete();
      //here to decrease counter for both user
      //user1
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user1Id).update({
        'friendsCounter':FieldValue.increment(-1)
      });
      //user2
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user2Id).update({
        'friendsCounter':FieldValue.increment(-1)
      });
    }
  });
}
```

ok now also everything going fine .. lets say user1 deleted his friend user 2 , by the previous `function`the Friends id which is `ABCDEF`has been deleted so next time if user 2 want to do the same opretion it will fail because Friends ids are not exist anymore ..

the problem IS :
lets say these two users are still friends and
these two user visited each others profiles and hit the button at the same time which is call the pervious `function` (deleteFriend) so they gonna get the same return value which is (yes exists) then will be double decrease value for both of them instead of one as required .

means if their `friendsCount` was 1 both of them when they was a friend so tee value will be -1 instead 0 because there two operation was proceed

and this happen only if these two user hit the button at the same moment , but if the user 1 hit the button before user 2 then user 2 want to do same operation so he ganna fail because `friendId` was deleted by user1 operation as a condition statement in previous function ..

```
if(value.exists) i thought it too fast to delete friendIds before it give same result to other user if they together call the function at the same time
```

of course i can prevent the button of calling the delete function in case one of these user is already deleted other but I didn't see this as a strong solution since i can't grantee traffic jam or any reason else like bad users behavior .. etc , also basically i can't do it because delete button must be available as long as they still a friends

Note: this also happen in addFriends buttom call too if two users hit it at the same time , double value +2 instead one ..

i need any way to avoid server to give same result if there was two user query same doc at the same time , or any good solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to both read and write a document to update it, you should [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) to prevent the race condition that you now have when multiple users perform the operation around the same time.

Here you definitely want to use a transaction, because if the delete fails for whatever reason, the decrement operation should also fail (and vice versa).

The FlutterFire documentation on [transactions](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage#transactions) also has a good explanation and example code to get started.

Comment: thanks for offering to me this awesome answer Puff , but if you edited my code with transaction example in my case i will be gladly thankful to you , i am using dart , flutter which i have Difficulties to learn from link you shared , Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but that's not how Stack Overflow works. I recommend giving it a try yourself, and posting back if you get stuck.

Comment: based on the documentation it says Note: this could be done without a transaction ,by updating the population using FieldValue.increment() , however it didn't solve my issue .. i m trying to prevent the same query result that will give user the same result in case they hit the button at the same time ..

Comment: I understand the use-case, and it will require a transaction (which is the answer to this question). Did my explanation of why you need a transaction make sense? --- If you have problems getting the transaction to work, I recommend posting a new question with the [minimal code that reproduces where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: thanks, either with transection or not , in all cases it will return the same value result from server which is (YES  EXIST) then two input of these two user  will go successful to the server DOUBLE decrease instead of one which is the wanted as only one doc deleted !!!, if there is only  one second  as a duration between two user query so everything is ok because between this duration the doc will be no longer EXIST for other user query so it's operation will fail as wanted , but the issue if two user hit the operation at the same time and bath will get the same result (YES  EXIST)

Comment: i have no problem with counter as mush as the query is . the main issue is the same result of query .. i handle the counter as well , also i mentioned it just to try explain the duplicated query result from two user at the same

Comment: "thanks, either with transection or not , in all cases it will return the same value result from server which is (YES EXIST) then two input of these two user will go successful to the server DOUBLE decrease instead of one which is the wanted as only one doc deleted" That is not how transactions in Firestore work. When you use a transaction, you load the document by calling `get()` on that transaction, and then call `set` or `update` on the transaction to indicate what the new value should become. Based on this, Firestore detects whether there was a conflicting update, and retries if needed.

Comment: "That is not how transactions in Firestore work" exactly , basically transection has no relation of my question topic

Comment: i read the whole documentation and work hard literally on it as test code on my IDE , nothing effect my issue since transection is only prevent the race condition but not query race at the same moment

Comment: I'm sorry, maybe I'm not understanding the problem, but I don't see any query in your question. **The code in your question does a `get()` and then performs two writes based on what it read from the database. If you want all of that to happen atomically, you need a transaction.** If the problem is actually something else, please edit your question to show the actual code of the problem.

Comment: please take look again in my question .. i edited it

Comment: None of the code there is calling a transaction, which is the only way to address the problem as far as I can see. Instead of explaining more about where you are stuck now, I recommend trying to implement the transaction based approach I described.

Comment: i am so so sorry i was confused , i thought the transaction is only for count field .. i wasnt know it also can detect the doc changed too .. it is work perfect Now as wanted ,, i really have no words to thank you . TRULY THANKS FOR THIS AWSOME ANSWER , My bad :(

Comment: Good to hear you got it working with the transaction @NadiaYaseen 